# How to filter out enabled buttons in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a table with 20 buttons - half of them are disabled and th other half is enabled. Is it possible to filter out the enabled buttons and click all of them in for loop? (elements that I want to click -> class="fa fa-check")
I have problem with filtering disabled buttons.

Disabled buttons have attribute 'disabled' with value 'disabled'. This is the only difference between enabled and disabled buttons.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; ++i) { //numberOfRows
                var button = element.all(by.repeater('tulemus in noue')).get(i);
                button.getAttribute('disabled').then(function(status) {
                    if (I dont know how to verify the right status) {
                          $$('.fa-check').get(i).click();
                          console.log('enabled element clicked');
                    } else {
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log('element is disabled');
                    }
                });
            }
```

[HTML code for two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF1mz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **each()** to iterate the on array elements rather using for loop in javascript. You can follow the below code:

```
   element.all(by.repeater('tulemus in noue')).each(function(button,index){
            button.getAttribute('disabled').then(function(status) {
                if(!status&&index=0){
                  button.click();//click if button is enabled
                 }
               else {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log('element is disabled');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Awesome, it almost works for me. Now I have a problem, that I did not mention before. There are 4 enabled elements in each row and I want to click first enabled element in each row. At the moment test clicks every one of them.

Comment: @SanderLepik cool. Sure, i can help to fix this problem as well. Can past UI page?

Comment: Here is the link to html: https://www.upload.ee/image/6355342/Capture1.PNG
I have marked enabled buttons with red arrows.

So I have to click every fourth enabled element in the list.
Here is the picture of UI: https://www.upload.ee/image/6355357/Capture3.PNG
4 disabled elements and 4 enabled elements, I need to click only the button with 'Jah'
@SureshSalloju

Comment: Put statement element.all(by.name("tulemu")).get(3).click(); in if statement in above code.

Comment: This way the test clicks on disabled element.

Comment: sorry, i did not get you @SanderLepik

Comment: First solution you gave me works almost, but needs one more thing. At the moment test clicks through every enabled element on the page, but I need test to click on the first enabled element, then skip clicking 3 next enabled elements and then again click enabled element and so on...

Comment: https://www.upload.ee/image/6355398/Capture4.PNG

That is the solution, I need to have.

Comment: The syntax 'index=0' is invalid, I tried index===0 and index==0, but they did not work.

Comment: Can paste me HTML code related to two levels  1-> for each row-2 each button in each row. We need to update the locator for two levels for iterating row wise and column wise

Comment: Do you know the solution? @SureshSalloju

Comment: Hey @SanderLepik we will have a call at 8PM IST. i need to have look at application. add my skype id - sallojusuresh

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `filter()` method to achieve the same,

```
element.all(by.repeater('tulemus in noue')).filter(function(button){
  return button.isEnabled().then(function(isEnabled){
       return isEnabled;
    })
 }).each(function(enabledButton){
       enabledButton.click();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use isEnable protractor function. This returns a boolean where the button is enabled or not.
Applied in your code would be:

```
var enabledButtons = element.all(by.repeater('tulemus in noue'))
.filter(button => { return button.isEnabled() });
```

and there you have all enabled buttons in the page stored in enabledButtons array of elements. You can now use them, or keep filtering them. For example, you could filter only the visible buttons like this:

```
var visibleButtons = enabledButtons.filter(button => { return button.isDisplayed() }));
```

Hope it helps.